# Golang execute function using flags

Tags: function, go, go-flag

How can I execute a specific function by entering a flag, for example, I have three flags:

```
    wordPtr
    numbPtr
    forkPtr
```

And when executing a single one, the function that calls is executed:

```
.\data -wordPtr Test
```

When executing that flag, only the word function is executed:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

var (
    wordPtr string
    numbPtr int
    forkPtr bool
)

func main() {

    flag.StringVar(&wordPtr, "word", "foo", "a string")
    flag.IntVar(&numbPtr, "numb", 42, "an int")
    flag.BoolVar(&forkPtr, "fork", false, "a bool")
    flag.Parse()

    if wordPtr != `` {
        word(wordPtr)
    }

    if numbPtr != 0 {
        numb(numbPtr)
    }

    if forkPtr {
        fork(forkPtr)
    }

}

func word(word string) {
    fmt.Println("word:", word)
}

func numb(numb int) {
    fmt.Println("numb:", numb)
}

func fork(fork bool) {
    fmt.Println("fork:", fork)
}
```

But, when I execute the last flag, all functions are executed

```
PS C:\golang> .\logdata.exe -fork
word: foo
numb: 42      
fork: true    
PS C:\golang>
```

Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide default values for the `word` and `numb` flags, which means if you don't provide them as cli arguments, they will get the default value.

And after `flag.Parse()` you only test if `wordPtr` is not empty or `numbPtr` is not `0`, and since the default values are not these, the tests will pass and the functions will be executed.

If you use the empty string and `0` as the defaults:

```
flag.StringVar(&wordPtr, "word", "", "a string")
flag.IntVar(&numbPtr, "numb", 0, "an int")
```

Then if you don't provide these as cli arguments, your tests will not pass:

```
.\logdata.exe -fork
```

Will output:

```
fork: true
```

If you want to test if `word` or `numb` was provided as cli arguments, see [Check if Flag Was Provided in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35809252/check-if-flag-was-provided-in-go).

Answer (score 0):

According to https://pkg.go.dev/flag#StringVar

> StringVar defines a string flag with specified name, default value, and usage string. The argument p points to a string variable in which to store the value of the flag.

So it means in your case `"foo"` - will be default value for `wordPtr`, `42` for `numbPtr` and `false` for `forkPtr`.